# How to get data from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
table 1:
    item_id - id of item
    child_id - id of item (child)

table 2:
    id - auto increment
    name - varchar
```

I have two names: item name and child name, and I want to get child ID.
In tables item names are repeated but have different parents. I want to get id of item name "A" which is a child of item "B".

How to do it?

Comment: Use a `JOIN`. Please learn SQL basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT child.id
FROM table1 AS child
JOIN table2 AS pc ON child.id = pc.child_id
JOIN table1 AS parent ON pc.parent_id = parent.id
WHERE parent.name = "B"
AND child.name = "A"
```